# Getting an error message when I run this shell script ? line 4: [: missing `]'

Tags: bash

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error Message ?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
        curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE"
        if [ $http_code != 200]; then
                echo " $LINE URL not available"
                exit 1
        fi
        echo " $LINE"
        done < url-list.txt
```

Comment: This is the error message I'm seeing: line 4: [: missing `]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use `$http_code`, but never declare it, and moreover, space is mandatory before closing test `]`

So :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url; do
    http_code=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$url")
    if ((http_code != 200)); then
        echo " $url URL not available"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo " $url"
done < url-list.txt
```

### Note :

- `(( ))` is for bash arithmetic
- prefer the bash test in the form `[[ ]]`, it's more powerfull and less error prone